# MongoID treated as array by DoctrineODM

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use a ReferenceOne for a MongoDB ODM Entity, but then the Doctrine Hydrator file is generated, the following error is returned:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoId as array in
>   /var/www/project/data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator/ApplicationDocumentTokenEntryHydrator.php

Here's the definition of the property in question:

```
/**
         * Page Mongo Id from Pages entry
         *
         * @ODM\Field(name="pageInternalId", type="object_id")
         * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Page\Document\PagesEntry")
         * @var \MongoId
         */
        protected $pageInternalId;
```

I dug a little in the generated Hydrator and in the DoctrineODMModule and found out that the following snippet is the problem

```
if (isset($this->class->fieldMappings['pageInternalId']['simple']) && $this->class->fieldMappings['pageInternalId']['simple']) {
                $className = $this->class->fieldMappings['pageInternalId']['targetDocument'];
                $mongoId = $reference;
            } else {
                $className = $this->unitOfWork->getClassNameForAssociation($this->class->fieldMappings['pageInternalId'], $reference);
                **$mongoId = $reference['$id'];**
            }
```

For some reason, the fieldMapping is not considered/set as "simple" - if I understand it correctly, if I can set it as such, it will enter the first clause and should work properly. However, I didn't find anything in the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html) about setting a property as "simple". How is that value determined, can it be set when defining the property?

I left the unrelated (imho) parts, if any more information is required, I will provide it. Thank you in advance!

I'm using DoctrineODMModule 0.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The field should be mapped either as `@ReferenceOne` or as `@Field` - combining these two may be the culprit of issue. Apart from that, property mapped as `@ReferenceOne` will contain a referenced object (from code's point of view, in database it'll be in fact `MongoID` but you don't need to care about it since it's ODM's task).

Comment: Actually, adding the 'simple="true"' option when defining the property almost fixed it - it now works, but something else caught my attention - the generated hydrator has the following line: 

$return = $this->dm->getReference($className, $id);

which, by documentation, returns only "a partial object that only has its identifier populated", which, imho is useless (I already have the identificator value from the field). Can someone provide pointers how to proceed?

Comment: The partial object is a `Proxy` that will be initialized and load all its data once you need them (i.e. upon first property/method access that is not getting the id) - it's for sake of lazy loading

Comment: Yea, it turned out that it works properly but Xdebug does not parse them correctly, for some reason.